# coping or saving variable in lambda expression in C#

Tags: c#, variables, lambda

how can I copy or save variable in Lambda expression

for example :

```
int i = 0;
Button btnTest=new Button();
Form1.Add(btnTest);
btnTest.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
};
i = 1;
```

in this code when I click on `btnTest` it Shows the new value (1) I want it to show the old value (0) how can I do this

Comment: There is no lambda-expression in the code you've posted. I think you misunderstand what the term means. An anonymous-method is not the same thing as a lambda-expression.

Comment: In you expression body, make sure you capture the value of `i`, say with `var j = i;` and then use that in the `MessageBox.Show` call. This Eric Lippert blog entry explains things: https://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/

Comment: @Flydog57 "In you expression body" - that's not going to help (unless you wanted to say something along "loop body" assuming OP has a loop around the code shown in the post)... OP has to create another variable outside and keep it not modified... which seem to be exactly opposite of what they want... (otherwise why would they ask the question?)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: in his code, the delegate body he's creating for the `Click` event is capturing `i`. When he captures it, the value is 0, but when the click happens, it has changed to 1, so that is what is used. By assigned the value to a separate variable (that is stable until the Cclick happens), he gets his desired behavior

Comment: HassamFares if you are ok to create copy of the variable  - than indeed it is covered in many similar questions on SO (I picked one as duplicate which also covers in details @Flydog57 comments + Eric Lipper's blog link). It looked to me that you *could not* for some reason to create a copy of the variable - if it indeed the case make sure to [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: thanks ,
creating copy of the variable works perfectly